# Server-side Blazor: How to persist user authentication after refreshing the page?

Tags: authentication, cookies, storage, blazor, blazor-server-side

What is the correct and safe way to persist the user authentication state after refreshing the page?

So far I created a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` that reads the state from the Browser Storage and it works fine, however I came across many opinions that this is not safe to keep sensitive data there, which are in my case Id, Name, Last Name, Role and TimeStamp of the user (in a form of encrypted JSON saved via `ASP.NET Core Protected Browser Storage`).

I've read about many other possibilities, but none seem to be the right one:

- Cookie - in Server-Side Blazor (Razor Components) it's only possible to create/read a cookie on the initial Http request, what makes it impossible to work if the user logs-in afterwards
- `CircuitHandler` - after refresh there's completely new Circuit established, so all the session information get lost
- Linking current session to the User's IP - in majority of cases it remains the same after refreshing, but it's also not safe and not reliable enough

So what am I missing here to make it work right? Are there any other possibilities for server-side Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your contribution, I went through a lot of your posts already and they really cleared many things up for me :)

The sources I've read about it mentioned Cookies as a better way for that, only.

Currently my solution is that i just serialize `ClaimsIdentity` directly into Json and save encoded string into Storage. The biggest concern I have is that no matter how hard encoded the string would be, anybody could just copy this and decode in his own code, even via mentioned previously `ASP.NET Core Protected Browser Storage` and simply change his role to get extended access and decode again.

That's why I thought about mplementing some kind of Storage OnChange event handler that would force the user to provide login information again and download fresh data from the database or Storage revalidation after x minutes whether it's still in line with Db.